# Is it possible to determine if a script is running within a task?

Tags: plugin-development, tasks

I have a chunk of PHP code which *should not* be run if the script is being executed from a task.

We already have these methods, which are similar to what I'm looking for:

- `craft()->isConsole()` - Whether the script is running in the console.
- `craft()->request->isCpRequest()` - Whether the script is running in the CP.

**Is there a way to tell if the script is running inside of a task?**

(Since my research has turned up nothing so far, I opened a [related feature request...](https://craftcms.uservoice.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/16112530-an-istask-method-to-determine-if-script-is-occ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`TasksService->getRunningTask()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/TasksService#getRunningTask-detail) will tell you if a task *is currently running*. However, it doesn't tell you whether a particular chunk of code is being executed by that Task or by some other function.

The most straightforward solution I can think of would be to write yourself a little helper method to check whether the call stack includes a Task class:

```
static function inTask()
{
   foreach(debug_backtrace() as $caller)
   {
      if (substr($caller['file'], -8) === 'Task.php') return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Add that to your plugin class, and then you can call it anywhere you need:

```
if (MyPlugin::inTask()) ...
```